# Регламентированно и регламентировано

Tags: нн

«Регламентированно и регламентировано». В предложении: «Все регламентированно для разных категорий граждан»...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно с одним «н»: **регламентировано**.

См. **«Орфографический словарь»:**

[http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=Регламентированный&all=x](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

Answer (score 0):

Краткие страдательные причастия пишутся с одной ‟н”.
[Ссылка на Грамоту.](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_106)

Comment: А если в качестве прилагательного? *У нас всё регламентированное (регламнтированно). Вот такое у нас всё.*

Comment: Не понял ничего. Тут причастие, а не прилагательное. В предложении: ‟Все наши правила строго регламентированы” — также причастие.

Comment: *Оно регламентировано кем-то; оно регламентированное само по себе* (здесь значение прилагательного).

Comment: Нет времени на спор, да и желания.

Comment: Просто интересно, понимаете ли вы разницу.

Comment: Похоже, что нет.